# How can I generate heatmaps from specific sections of data using GnuPlot? ('splot', 'every', 'using' incompatibilites etc.)

Tags: plot, gnuplot, heatmap

I am attempting to generate heatmaps from a data file I've been generating. I could re-format the data however I like, but for the time being, let's say it's a list of 16 numbers that I'd like put into a 4x4 heatmap. However, I have many sets of these 16 numbers sequentially in the same file, and hope to eventually animate them together (something I am more comfortable with, and will come later)

However, for the time being, I cannot find a way to get GnuPlot to select only certain sections of the data file while still plotting properly. A loose example of what I would've thought it WOULD look like:

```
plot "SortedData.txt" every ::0::15 w image
```

or:

```
splot "SortedData.txt" every ::0::15
```

Both give me errors and fail to render. I could label the data values with an x-y coordinate if needed, but the task is fairly repetitive: I just want the first 16 points mapped, and then the ability to iterate once and have the next 16 points mapped on their own, etc. Stripping the data file to just the first 16 points and removing the 'every' command confirms that it can plot, but trying to specify even just the first 16 manually messes it up.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? The "every" command has been fairly nebulous and seems largely incompatible with images / 3-D data. Also, I am running on Windows, so piping in linux commands is something I'd like to avoid.

Thanks!

edit: Here is 4 example frames of the data. Reformatting it to, say, present as a matrix or label with pixel addresses are all something I can do if needed.

```
0.000000    -49.314654  -44.425234  -46.613870  -48.494232  -46.884806  -46.553071  -46.555624  -43.755972  -47.817691  -42.481637  -46.819782  -44.347586  -49.487077  -47.291832  -45.140636  -47.945934
0.839906    -49.325396  -44.425493  -46.613214  -48.501283  -46.887236  -46.550858  -46.555285  -43.752786  -47.814706  -42.453793  -46.814333  -44.329492  -49.493501  -47.289394  -45.133555  -47.944045
1.679721    -49.336151  -44.425787  -46.612573  -48.508348  -46.889684  -46.548645  -46.554958  -43.749626  -47.811707  -42.425757  -46.808866  -44.311344  -49.499930  -47.286951  -45.126476  -47.942155
2.519466    -49.346920  -44.426117  -46.611946  -48.515427  -46.892152  -46.546431  -46.554641  -43.746492  -47.808695  -42.397525  -46.803382  -44.293140  -49.506365  -47.284501  -45.119398  -47.940264
```

Comment: Please post an example of your data file that contains (at least) two frames. Are the frames separated, for example by one or two blank lines?

Comment: I just updated the post with a reply to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that each line in your data file has 17 elements. I assume that the first column is not part of your image data. I would format the remaining 16 values as a 4x4 matrix, with each frame separated by two blank lines:

```
-49.314654  -44.425234  -46.613870  -48.494232  
-46.884806  -46.553071  -46.555624  -43.755972  
-47.817691  -42.481637  -46.819782  -44.347586  
-49.487077  -47.291832  -45.140636  -47.945934


-49.325396  -44.425493  -46.613214  -48.501283  
-46.887236  -46.550858  -46.555285  -43.752786  
-47.814706  -42.453793  -46.814333  -44.329492  
-49.493501  -47.289394  -45.133555  -47.944045


-49.336151  -44.425787  -46.612573  -48.508348  
-46.889684  -46.548645  -46.554958  -43.749626  
-47.811707  -42.425757  -46.808866  -44.311344  
-49.499930  -47.286951  -45.126476  -47.942155


-49.346920  -44.426117  -46.611946  -48.515427  
-46.892152  -46.546431  -46.554641  -43.746492  
-47.808695  -42.397525  -46.803382  -44.293140  
-49.506365  -47.284501  -45.119398  -47.940264
```

You can then visualize each frame with the command

```
plot "data.dat" index FRAME matrix w image
```

where `FRAME` is 0, 1, 2 or 3.